# Execute commands from inside a bash script

Tags: bash

I want to run the following commands from a bash script:

```
sudo cat << EOF>> /etc/profile

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_22/
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:/opt/tomcat/bin:${PATH}

EOF

sudo source /etc/profile
```

But a get a following errors:

```
/home/ak/init-script.sh: line 40: /etc/profile: Permission denied
sudo: source: command not found
```

Any help about how to achieve what i want?

Antonis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get "Permission denied" error, when trying to write to /etc/profile. This is because sudo is applied only to the first command - cat, but process writing to /etc/profile has the privileges of your normal user.

This is why this file does not get created. There is a [workaround](http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2007/09/26/unixlinux-redirect-output-as-sudo/), but I don't think you need it, since if you just need to export some variables, you can do it directly from your shell:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_22/
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:/opt/tomcat/bin:${PATH}
```

If you need to load settings from /etc/profile to your shell, you can just run `source /etc/profile` without sudo, it is not needed there.

Answer (score 3):

`source` is a builtin `bash` command, not a program you can run with `sudo`.  You have to use `sudo` on the entire script